# How to create multiple identical intent-filters for same activity, each will be used for a different action?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

Suppose I have an activity that can handle sending images from other apps, which is defined similar to what you see here:

```
    <activity
        android:name="..."
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="..."
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter android:label="new collection" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="new collection" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

All good and well, but what if I want to add identical intent-filters (handling sending images to the app), yet this time with a different label that I can check in code which is which ?

For example, I could add an intent-filter for "add to existing collection" .

I've searched for attributes that I can set by myself, which won't affect the way the OS resolves the intent, but I've failed.

How do I do that correctly?
Do I really have to create a new activity ?

Comment: add an alias: <activity-alias> in the manifest

Comment: @pskink Can you please show an example to what you mean? Also, what should I put in the code in order to differentiate between the actions ("add to existing collection", "new collection" ) ?

Comment: add activity-alias with attrs: name,  targetActivity and label, also copy the intent-filter,  in your Activity use getIntent().getComponent()

Comment: @pskink This looks like it's working. Please put it as an answer. Also, BTW, the new "activity-alias" tag must be added after the activity tag, and you can put whatever you wish for its name. The "label" isn't needed, but it is useful. Are there any important things I need to know about this technique ?

Comment: hmm, i see only this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add an activity alias in your manifest:

```
    <activity-alias
        android:name="..."
        android:targetActivity="<original activity name>"
        android:label="add to existing collection"
    >
        <intent-filter>
        ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
```

you can use `label` in `activity-alias` level or `intent-filter` level, in your Activity use Intent's Component to differentiate what Component was used